# Vectormagic.com-style-design by Inkscape with Bitmap-trace aka potrace?

Tags: inkscape

I have used the [Vectormagic.com](http://vectormagic.com/home) `-hxck` i.e. copy-pasting to get quantified and nice-looking pictures fast but doing this is too slow with overwhelming amount of pictures. My friend is mocking that this thing cannot be done quickly with offline `-tools` but I feel the story is different, it probably requires some expertise to use the tools such as `bitmap-trace` in **Inkscape** correctly.

For simplicity, suppose you have some simple comic character with 10 colors, background transparent and alpha-channel added. **How can you improve the quality?** Inkscape uses the term `quantification` with bitmap-trace but I cannot yet understand what is actually happening under the cover when Vectormagic.com does the trick and makes the photo looking good.

Please, explain. And special plus if you can provide reproducible commands, look potrace/autotrace are commandline tools eventually.

**Perhaps related**

1. https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/7798/9379

Comment: I don't really understand. You're asking someone to explain the VectorMagic proprietary method for tracing raster images? I doubt anyone can or will do that. I've never used Inkscape, but be aware, it si not the only offline tracing tool on the market.

Comment: I was unable to post this earlier. Adobe Illustrator CS6 has a completely reworked tracing feature. When available, you may want to download the trial of Illustrator and test that feature.

Comment: @Scott: I am instead considering the cloud option when it comes public (I want to use things in any OS) -- I don't have a working machine even for CS6, more [here](http://superuser.com/questions/415932/fixing-corrupted-windows-7-professional-most-drivers-stopped-working-and-starti). Or well I am happy to go with FOSS -software, one can find always something to learn there -- they do not work that much differently to adobe pipeline, or so I hope...I need to open some  proprietary Adobe files in the future so I think I must have some adobe product, hopefully cloud enough...or?

Comment: @Scott: I think I am going to choose Mac -version over W (despite the battle between adobe and apple, heard some support problems emerging with macs, just rumour), I am not wanting to get OS dead while working...